# implementing card view in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cardview, androidx, material-components-android

I am trying to implement card view by implementing it in my `build.gradle.`
 However while doing this, I am getting an error. It is saying

> "Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX... less... (Ctrl+F1)"

I understand how to do it but am not sure if I should since I am not getting any build errors and my gradle is still syncing. Can someone tell me whats going on?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are using androidx libraries together with a very old version of support library of cardview.

Remove the dependency of support library

```
//implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:16.0.4'
```

and add:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

More info about [androidx here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

You have another option.

Just add the [`MaterialCard`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialCardView.md) included in the official [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

and in your xml you can use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
  ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open your project and make the compile and target version to 28 , then sync then go to refractor on toolbar of studio , there you will see migrate to android x just tap on that. It will resolved all your issue.